# using angular expressions in a django based webapp

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I recently started with django and I have experience with angularJS. I got pretty confused by the static media rendering of Django which uses the same moustache (`{{ }}`) as angular. So how to use angular expressions while working with django..

```
    <body>
    <h1>Including Static Media</h1>
    <img src="{% static "rango.jpg" %}" alt="Picture of Rango" /> <!-- Images -->
    </body>
```

Instead of using the rendering as it is, can i use something like 
    image `src="/static/images/xyz.jpg"`

However if I want to load my images or js script dynamically or if I have to make URL's dynamically using something like `ng-href="#!/{{redirectService(parameters)}}"`. It seems that syntax of both frameworks conflict alot. Can anyone help me regarding this.?

Comment: take a look at custom interpolators - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider

Comment: @YOU Yes, that might work. Could you please look at the question again, I added one more small doubt.!

Comment: sorry, i don't get your new update. in angular you can use ng-src for dynamic image source.

Comment: I meant to ask for static images itself, can i use the normal syntax that just appends the resource path to href =

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [the `{% verbatim %}` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) and/or [the `{% templatetag %}` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag).

From the docs:

> ### verbatim
>
> Stops the template engine from rendering the contents of this block
>   tag.
>
> A common use is to allow a JavaScript template layer that collides
>   with Django’s syntax. For example:
>
> ```
> {% verbatim %}
>     {{if dying}}Still alive.{{/if}} 
> {% endverbatim %}
> ```
>
> You can also designate a specific closing tag, allowing the use of `{% endverbatim %}` as part of the unrendered contents:
>
> ```
> {% verbatim myblock %}
>     Avoid template rendering via the {% verbatim %}{% end verbatim %} block.
> {% endverbatim myblock %}
> ```

---

> ### templatetag
>
> Outputs one of the syntax characters used to compose template tags.
>
> Since the template system has no concept of “escaping”, to display one
>   of the bits used in template tags, you must use the `{% templatetag %}`
>   tag.
>
> The argument tells which template bit to output:
>
> ```
> Argument        | Outputs 
> ————————————————|————————
> openblock       | {% 
> closeblock      | %} 
> openvariable    | {{
> closevariable   | }} 
> openbrace       | { 
> closebrace      | } 
> opencomment     | {#
> closecomment    | #}
> ```
>
> Sample usage:
>
> ```
> {% templatetag openblock %} url 'entry_list' {% templatetag closeblock %}
> ```

Comment: seems promising, looking into it